# When using "vertex AI gamini api" on the spring boot server, is it correct to create an object of vertex AI every time?

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, google-gemini

I'm making AI service using spring boot and Google's vertex AI.

I have this piece of code:

````
public PredictedResult prediction(MultipartFile file) {
        String inferSpeciesPrompt = "my prompt";
        try (VertexAI vertexAi = new VertexAI("my-project", "asia-northeast3");) {
            GenerationConfig generationConfig =
                    GenerationConfig.newBuilder()
                            .setMaxOutputTokens(2048)
                            .setTemperature(0.1F)
                            .setTopK(15)
                            .setTopP(0.7F)
                            .build();
            GenerativeModel model = new GenerativeModel("gemini-pro-vision", generationConfig, vertexAi);
            List<SafetySetting> safetySettings = Arrays.asList(
                    SafetySetting.newBuilder()
                            .setCategory(HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH)
                            .setThreshold(SafetySetting.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH)
                            .build(),
                    SafetySetting.newBuilder()
                            .setCategory(HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT)
                            .setThreshold(SafetySetting.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH)
                            .build(),
                    SafetySetting.newBuilder()
                            .setCategory(HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT)
                            .setThreshold(SafetySetting.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH)
                            .build(),
                    SafetySetting.newBuilder()
                            .setCategory(HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT)
                            .setThreshold(SafetySetting.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH)
                            .build()
            );
            List<Content> contents = new ArrayList<>();
            contents.add(Content.newBuilder()
                    .setRole("user")
                    .addParts(PartMaker.fromMimeTypeAndData(file.getContentType(), file.getBytes())) 
                    .addParts(Part.newBuilder().setText(inferSpeciesPrompt))
                    .build());
            GenerateContentResponse generateContentResponse = model.generateContent(contents, safetySettings);
            String text = generateContentResponse.getCandidates(0).getContent().getParts(0).getText().replace("```json", ""); 
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
            PredictedResult predictedResult = objectMapper.readValue(text, PredictedResult.class);
            if (predictedResult.getLivingThings() == "false") {
                throw new NoCreatureException();
            }
            return predictedResult;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            GeminiException exception = new GeminiException("validation", "try another image");
            exception.addValidation("image", e.getMessage());
            throw exception;
        }
    }
````

For url's request using "gemini", I created a new instance of vertex AI each time to deliver the prediction results. But I think this way of generating instances every time seems inefficient.
Is there any way to efficiently utilize the ai model?

The gemini of "vetex ai" is used as a multimodal model, and when I send a specific image, I get the prediction in the json format. And once I send an image and receive the results of the json format, instead of exchanging conversations, the role of ai ends there.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i understand your issue.

gemini-pro-vision is not conversational it is single request multimodal image and text.

If you want to hold on a conversation you need to use gemini-pro and drop the images. Even with image you are still sending the full conversation history with each added conversation input from the user.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. My question is that if api request using "prediction" function above occurs, "prediction" function creates "vertex ai" object every time. "vertex ai" simply responds with json format the prediction result of the provided image, and the role ends. If multiple people generate traffic corresponding to the request, I'm worried that the object of "vertex ai" is created in memory every time will lead to excessive memory usage. So, I wonder if there is any other way to solve this problem.